# Optimal locking - append-only store

Tags: sql-server, performance, locking

I'm designing an internal event store library based off SQL Server. One challenge I had to solve is to allow concurrent writes while still being able to generate a reliable Log Sequence Number (LSN) that could be used to consume the stream of events in order as they appear.

The way I'm solving this is by having a `loose_position bigint IDENTITY(1, 1)` column and a `strict_position bigint NULL` column which will get updated by a single writer and used as a consuming checkpoint. The sequencer does something like the following in a `READ COMMITTED` transaction:

```
DECLARE @maxPosition bigint;

SELECT @maxPosition = MAX(strict_position)
FROM RecordedEvent WITH(READPAST)
WHERE strict_position IS NOT NULL;

WITH seq AS (
    SELECT id, @maxPosition + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY loose_position) AS strict_position
    FROM RecordedEvent WITH (READPAST)
    WHERE strict_position IS NULL
)
UPDATE r WITH (READPAST)
SET strict_position = @maxPosition + seq.strict_position
FROM RecordedEvent r
INNER JOIN seq ON seq.id = r.id;
```

I wanted to prevent the sequencer from being blocked by newly inserted records and vice-versa, so I've used `READPAST` which seems to work, but I'm not sure that's the best approach.

Please note that I also have a `UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ON loose_position` and a `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ON strict_position WHERE strict_position IS NOT NULL`, but I'm not entirely sure how these affects locking.

Could someone confirm that my current solution is appropriate or if there are better ways to achieve what I want?

Comment: Are you trying to create a message queue?  Perhaps [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/169475/improve-table-design-to-improve-performance) helps?

Comment: If you are just looking for a way to generate a sequence of numbers for each new entry in your stack, perhaps [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36603/handling-concurrent-access-to-a-key-table-without-deadlocks-in-sql-server/36725#36725) will help.

Comment: [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175137/transaction-with-lock-on-a-specific-table/175163#175163) may be helpful as well - it talks about how to reliably generate a sequence of numbers while maintaining great concurrency.

Comment: @MaxVernon Thanks for your comments. Much appreciated. I'm reviewing all that!

Comment: My pleasure.  Let us know if you decide one of those approaches works for you,

Comment: @plalx How did you solve it in the end?